# Is it possible to programatically change Winforms splitivew pagesize?

Tags: c#, winforms, splitview

I would like to change the size of the pages dynamically based on events during runtime.

[image]

Comment: Yes. can you give an example of the code you have tried?

Comment: I've tried all of its properties. Why can't you just tell which one is it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the SplitContainer in a Winforms application.

```
splitContainer1.SplitterDistance = 200;
```